# Can't set correct desktop resolution on Windows 7 after playing Mirror's Edge

Tags: windows-7, desktop, resolution

Ever since I launched Mirror's Edge, my entire system seems to think that my monitor is 1600x1200, when actually it's 1920x1080. The game would only go up to 1600x1200, Windows will only go up to 1600x1200, and even my video drivers will only go up that high. The monitor isn't even that aspect ratio. I've rebooted the system to no effect, and installed the latest graphics drivers for my Radeon 5770, unplugged it and re-plugged it, etc. My secondary screen is still working perfectly correctly. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I unplugged and re-plugged it- but it was loose on the *other* end, in the screen itself, not on the GPU end.

Answer (score 1):

If you click the 'Advanced settings' link in the Windows 7 Adjust Resolution control panel, and then click on the Monitor tab, you can uncheck the box that says "hide modes that this monitor cannot display" and it should then give you more resolution options.

I don't know why Mirror's Edge would do this to your computer (it seems odd that it would have such an effect) though the better solution I think would be to try and reinstall the drivers for the monitor itself. You can do that by going into Device Manager and under the monitors group, find the display that's having this issue and updating the drivers.